# problem in search

Tags: search

D7

I have this site http://thefracdepot.com/ I developed this at drupalgardens then move to other hosting. The problem is that at new hosting search not displaying all the nodes which have searched keyword. It only showing gallery and about us page. No other basic page is appearing. It was working fine at drupalgardens, and I also can see all products pages in google search, but my site search is not displaying related nodes.

note I have done re-indexing but still no luck.
Can anyone help in finding out the reason for this problem and solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content get re-indexed only after the next cron run. If you didn't run cron after re-indexing, the search will not show all the content.